# Revert the submit button back to it's initial state if input fields are empty or not correctly filled

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, contact-form

I am using the code below to replace the "send" text in a submit button of a contact form with loading_dots.gif image.

```
// Replace submit button text with loading gif 
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="images/loading/loading_dots.gif" />');
});
```

The form is validated before it's submitted. If one or more input field is not filled how can I revert the button back to it's initial state?

Comment: you use a change event to trigger the removal of the img

Comment: Avoid deprecated short form functions such as `.click`, use `.on`. Avoid hard-coded blobs of html in the js source code. Avoid paths in js. Avoid `.html` if at all possible. Use CSS class names to dynamically change the page when possible. Don't use XML self closing tags, html is *not* XML (even if it "works", lots of garbage works). Don't litter your source code with hard coded constants, use named constants at the top. Don't listen for button clicks, instead, listen for the form's `submit` event. You can submit a form other ways, for example, with the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   var oldHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<img src="images/loading/loading_dots.gif" />');
});
```

use this oldHtml if form is not validate properly

Answer (score 0):

**Assign initial html back to button if validation fails**

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
   var initialHtml = $(this).html();
   $(this).html('<img src="images/loading/loading_dots.gif" />');
   if(!ValidateData())
   {
     $(this).html(initialHtml);
   }
});

function ValidateData()
{
    // if not valid
    return false;
}
```